# trying to save the form input into a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, variables, input

I googled, and looked at stackoverflow and tried out the examples and i'm still having difficulties.

GOAL:  Create a form box where a user can enter a city name so i can capture it in a variable and use it to look up the city lattitue and longitute from goodle geocode api.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div>
  <form id="nameForm">
    <input id="cityForm" type="text" >
    <button id="subButton" type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and here is my code i tried:

`var theTerm = document.getElementById('cityForm').value;
console.log(theTerm);`

console output gives me nothing.

I stripped the code down and removed the weather api stuff from it but basically i'm concerned about how i can capture a city name that was entered and 'submit' by a user.  Here is the jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/zt28sbo3/1/

Comment: shouldn't you wait for user to enter something? Think it through a bit... page loads....you try to get a value immediately, before user can even see the form. What's the button for then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for an event (when the user has typed something). Something like so should work:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('foo');
element.addEventListener('blur', function () {
  var value = this.value;
  // API request here
});
```

```html
<input id="foo" />
```

You could also listen to the parent forms `submit` event:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('nameForm');
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevent normal form submission
  var value = document.getElementById('foo').value;
  console.log(value);
  // API request here
});
```

```html
<form id="nameForm">
  <input id="foo" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: not so sure that is the most appropriate event for allowing user to enter a city name in order to make an api request

Comment: Wow, nice answer!